# Object reference not set when using keypress to trigger a button in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a chat program, consisting of an input textbox and a send button, set up like this:

```
<input @bind="messageInput" size="50" @onkeydown="submitMessageInput" />

<button @onclick="Send">Send</button>
```

The `Send` method does this:

```
async Task Send()
        {
            if (messageInput.StartsWith("/login") .....
```

The `submitMessageInput` method looks like this in order to handle pressing enter rather than clicking the send button manually:

```
public async Task submitMessageInput(KeyboardEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter")
            {
                await Send();
            }
        }
```

If the button is clicked, it works fine. However if enter is pressed, the first line of the Send() method throws an object not set to instance of an object error.

I wonder if it's some kind of context issue that's making `messageInput` null? What's the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: `messageInput` gets changed on your input's `changed` event. That event is fired when the input loses focus. If you press enter, the input won't lose focus, therefore not updating the value of `messageInput`

Comment: This is something very complicated.

Comment: I see. Do you know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that `@bind="someString"` is an abbreviation that sets two properties, `@bind-value="someString"` and `@bind-value:event="onchange"`

The value therefore updates whenever a change event is registered, which is when the input loses focus.

To fix the issue you need to change `onchange` to `oninput`. It will then update the variable every time you enter a character, fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just change event **onkeydown** to **onkeyup**.
The fact is that the 'messageInput' field will be updated after the @onkeydown event, but the field has already been updated when the @onkeyup event occurs.

```
<input @bind-value="messageInput" size="50" @onkeyup="submitMessageInput" />
<button @onclick="Send">Send</button>
@code {
    protected string messageInput;
    public async Task submitMessageInput(KeyboardEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter") {
            await Send();
        }
    }

    protected async Task Send() {
        if (messageInput.StartsWith("/login")) {
            // to do
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If that were the case, then typing 'hello' and pressing enter would presumably work and give you 'hell'

Comment: Apparently, the case with Enter is special. Dereferencing occurs when the Enter key is pressed (I dont know why). However, in the context of the @onkeyup event, no dereferencing occurs, so you can normally works with the field.